# Rails: Update parent object when saving child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, a Conversation has many Messages. How to I update the `updated_at` attribute of a Conversation when a new Message in that Conversation is created/saved?

I'm aware of `:touch => true`, which does this, but it also updates Conversation when a Message is destroyed, which is not what I want.

Thanks.

Models

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages 
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use callback inside  Message class

```
after_save do
  conversation.update_attribute(:updated_at, Time.now)
end
```

Comment: can you tell me why it works even without mentioning `self.conversation...`. when and when not to use `self`?

Comment: @HungryCoder use **self** when you do attributes assignments to prevent any ambiguity (for instance, you have the same names local variables). But in that case **conversation** is not a local variable, but explicitly declared association (say, method's name)

Answer (score 70):

You can just define it on the relationship as well.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation, touch: true
end
```

(Source same as William G's answer: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch)

Comment: This doesn't run callbacks!! and most of the time you would want to do this is when you want to run parent callbacks.

Comment: From the original question: `How to I update the updated_at attribute of a Conversation when a new Message in that Conversation is created/saved?` The `.touch` method is mostly used to update timestamps. (From the documentation: `Saves the record with the updated_at/on attributes set to the current time.`) The most common usage of `touch` is probably for cache expiry.

If you want callbacks, there is an `after_touch` callback.

Comment: Another use is for sitemap timestamps, no callbacks desired in that case.

Comment: @chug2k id touch: true works on destroying the child object. means when an associated message is deleted will it update the conversation object??

Answer (score 10):

I prefer this solution for Rails 3:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation

  after_save :update_conversation

  def update_conversation
    self.conversation.touch
  end
end
```

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch