# Looking for a gem in rails that maintain the versions of every change made in data of particular model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rubygems

I have a model named Workflow associated (almost all kinds of association: one-to-many, many-to-many, etc.) with other tables. A user creates a workflow with all associated data and publishes the workflow. After that if a user edits and changes anything in workflow data or any associated table data then the  state changes from published to unpublished.

I need to save the previous published state of every change. So, basically I want save all the history and which change was made in workflows. Is there any gem that can help me out in solving this problem or any other suggestions ?

Comment: Paper Trail https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail seems to be a popular gem for doing this. In my current Rails project I wrote my own as an after_save callback.

Comment: @Dan I want to keep track of all data including associated data..I can have access to all version.I have show the user day wise history of changes made into data.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a sample of your model associations that you wish to track changes on? I still think Paper Trail could work for you. You set each model that you want history on `has_paper_trail`

Comment: Paper Trails does not change the version of parent if I made any change into any child data.It will change the version of child but not parent.lets say  workflow has many nodes and if I any change was made into the node's data I want workflow version should also change but paper trail does not do this.

Comment: I suppose if you want a change to a child to update the parent you could trigger that yourself using a callback on the child model. See this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736265/rails-update-parent-object-when-saving-child/6736313 for information on this.

Comment: Would this help? https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking