# Ruby ActiveRecord how to avoid Database delay/lock when child record callback is updating parent record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq project running a task creates multiple child records and updates the parent record to which this child object belongs. The database is Postgres.

The schema is give below. When the Child record is created, there is a before_create method that updates a flag in the Parent. The Parent has a before_save method to update a timestamp.

```
# t.boolean "is_updated", default: false
#  id                          :integer          not null, primary key
#t.datetime "updated_at"
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child

  def update_flag
   self.is_updated = true
  end

  before_save : set_updated_at

  def set_updated_at
    self.updated_at = Time.current 
  end
end


class ChildRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  before_create :update_parent_flag

  def update_parent_flag
    if self.parent.try(:update_flag)
      self.parent.save!
    end
  end
end
```

When the Sidekiq job creates just one Child record, there is no error. However when the job tries to create a larger bactch of Child records (35 in one example), the Job is in busy state for a long time. We can see that the Postgres connection is waiting for a lock in the Parent update.

**Update** The Sidekiq job updates or creates the batch of Child records in a single transaction.

```
def perform(params, options = {})
  children = params[:children] 
  #New transaction
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    children.each do |child|
      return_code, error = create_or_update_child_record(child)
      if return_code != :created
        Rails.logger.info error
      return
     end
  end
 end
```

The following is the blocking statement in the database.

```
UPDATE "Parent" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "Parent"."id" = $2
```

How can I avoid this lock when creating multiple Child records? Is there a better design?

Comment: `update_flag` appears to try and create a `Child` before the child is created it calls `update_parent_flag` which then calls `update_flag`, which tries to create a `Child`.... I am surprised you didn't end up in a `SystemStackError`. *"Is there a better design?"* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736265/rails-update-parent-object-when-saving-child

Comment: @engineersmnky I copied the wrong example. I have corrected it now. The `update_flag` just updates a boolean `is_updated` field in the `Parent` class.  I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: don't update the parent record from the child records -- do it once at the at the end  batch

Comment: @dbugger Thanks. It is one of my options. However the parent update is critical and having it as a callback makes sure it is updated anywhere I create the Child record.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the necessity to have an update flag in the Parent? We'd need to know more about its purpose. Also, are `params[:children]` all of the same Parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting each Child one-by-one is going to be inefficient regardless. You need a way to bulk insert Child objects. This bulk insert method would update their Parents only once at the end.

I prefer [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to Rails' [insert_all](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all) primarily because it can do model validations.

```
# Make the Child models, but do not insert them.
children = [Child.new(...), Child.new(...), ...]

# Validate and insert all the children in bulk
Child.import! children, validate: true

# Get their Parent's ids
parent_ids = children.map(&:parent_id).uniq

# Update their Parents
Parent
  .where(id: parent_ids)
  .update_all(
    is_updated: true,
    # update_all does not update updated_at
    updated_at: Time. current
  )
```

This executes one insert for the Childs and one update for their Parents.

Note: Consider if the is_updated flag is necessary. Can you rely on the updated_at timestamp alone?